# Getting regular text from wikipedia page

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, wikipedia

I am trying to get the text or the summary text from a random wikipedia page, i need it, to be a list of lists of words (list of sentences) in the end.

I am using the following code

```
def get_random_pages_summary(pages = 0):
    import wikipedia
    page_names = [wikipedia.random(1) for i in range(pages)]
    return [[p,wikipedia.page(p).summary] for p in page_names]

def text_to_list_of_words_without_new_line(text):
    t = text.replace("\n", " ").strip()
    t1 = t.split()
    t2 = ["".join(w) for w in t1]
    return t2

text = get_random_pages_summary(1)

for i,row in enumerate(text):
    text[i][1] = text_to_list_of_words_without_new_line(row[1])

print text[0][1]
```

I am getting weird tokens, i assume they are a relic of the markdown code for the wikipedia page e.g

> Russian:', u'\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d

I found that it is probably happening when there is a quote from another language inside the English page, it also happens when having a range of years in the page e.g 2015-2016

I would like to convert all of these to regular words, and remove those that i can not convert to regular words.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is bothering you? the `\u` characters?

Comment: Try: `print text[0][1].encode('utf-8')` to display cyrillic characters

Comment: no, the u'\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d part